# Can you explain HOW bool can control loops?

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop, boolean, cin

I'm a beginner programmer in C++ (currently), and I've got a conceptual question.

I'm trying to filter a `cin` input to ensure that it is a one-or-two-digit integer between 01-04, and if it isn't, to produce an error and ask for a new input.

I'm also using `map` to give the user a list of options that, upon *valid* selection, routes inputs (integers) through any of several methods to produce a relevant result, but I'll ask a more specific version of this question elsewhere.

I found a snippet of code at http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/26821/ that is meant to validate an input. I sort of get it, except where the boolean condition is set inside the while loop. Because I don't understand it, it makes it very difficult to edit or make sure that I'm manipulating it right.

Here is the example code:

```
int main()
{
    int num;
    bool valid = false;

    while (!valid)
    {
        valid = true; //Assume the cin will be an integer.

        cout << "Enter an integer value: " << endl;
        cin >> num;

        if(cin.fail()) //cin.fail() checks to see if the value in the cin
                    //stream is the correct type, if not it returns true,
                    //false otherwise.
        {
            cin.clear(); //This corrects the stream.
            cin.ignore(); //This skips the left over stream data.
            cout << "Please enter an Integer only." << endl;
            valid = false; //The cin was not an integer so try again.
        }
    }

    cout << "You entered: " << num << endl;

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
```

And here is my code (the entire thing, to give context). I don't think it's complete, I just want to make sure I'm using the boolean right.

```
float _tmain(float argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    bool validInput = !true;

    map<string,int> Operations;
    Operations.insert(pair<string, int>("Addition", 01));
    Operations.insert(pair<string, int>("Subtraction", 02));
    Operations.insert(pair<string, int>("Multiplication", 03));
    Operations.insert(pair<string, int>("Division", 04));

    cout << "Welcome to OneOpCalc, what operation would you like to perform?" << endl;

    for(map<string, int>::iterator ii=Operations.begin(); ii!=Operations.end(); ++ii)
    {
        cout << (*ii).second << ": " << (*ii).first << endl;
    }

    while (!validInput)
    {
        cin >> operatorSelection;

        if (cin.fail() || operatorSelection < 4 || operatorSelection > 1)
        {
            cout << "Error: Invalid selection. Please choose a valid number." << endl << endl;
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore();
        }
    }
}
```

Does `while (!valid)` mean "While `valid` is *false*"? In my head, it's saying "While `valid` is `!valid`", which obviously, would always be false.

EDIT: Thanks for the answers guys, I'm looking through them all. One answer I keep getting goes too general; I understand that ! is NOT, and I understand the concept of flipping the bool using it. However the implicit logical implications are what confuse me. In any given statement, I am used to thinking of `!valid` as a way of flipping the `valid` value; Not testing a condition. It's the syntax of using it to test a condition that tricks me. In other words, writing `while(!valid)` reads literally to me as `while(NOTvalid)`, not `while(valid==false)`. I can't get myself to understand why in this case, `!valid` reads as a condition and not just a bit-flip.

Comment: `!` in C++ means NOT, the NOT operation returns the opposite of what it is applied to. Therefore `while(!valid)` is the same as `while(valid==false)`.

Comment: What a complicated way of doing `while(cin >> value)`.

Comment: @Rapptz: It's not a way of doing that.

Comment: @Robadob What confuses me is that since, by this point, `valid=false` already, doesn't `while(!valid)` mean `while(valid==true)` and vice-versa?

Comment: @DarkIron112 You should read `!` as a method that returns the opposite of `valid`. Have you look at the truth table? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table#Logical_negation

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Really? Enlighten me. What is the first loop accomplishing that `while(cin >> value)` wouldn't do?

Comment: @Rapptz: `while(cin >> value)` reads until failure.  His loop reads until success.  It would perhaps be similar to `while(!(cin >> value))`

Comment: @Robadob Thank you, please read my updated post; I keep having people explain this to me, and I added more detail that may help explain what exactly my confusion with this is.

Comment: @DarkIron112 The best way I can put it is that a condition evaluates to a boolean value, and the while/if statement only enters if the condition evaluated to true. This might be clearer if you read `!valid` as `NOT(valid)` a method that returns the boolean opposite.

Comment: @DarkIron112 `!value` does _not_ flip anything.  It doesn't change anything at all.  It is a value expression, which returns the value of its operand (here, `value`), inversed.  If `value` is true, `!value` is false, and vice versa.

Comment: @JamesKanze So, say I had `while (!value) {//}` where `bool value = false`; Does this mean "_while `value=true`, do {//}_"? In which case, I would want to at some point have a branch that flips `value` to `true`, or else I'd have an infinite loop?

Comment: @DarkIron112 If you have `while ( !value )`, and you never change `value` in the loop, the loop will either execute 0 times, or infinitely.  One standard check (in code review, etc.) is that a loop always makes progress; if the loop condition is based on a single `bool`, that means that there is code somewhere in the loop which flips it, and that that code can eventually be executed, given the state of the program when starting the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loops (and ifs) are controled by an expression of type `bool`.
In `while ( !valid )`, the expression is `!valid`, the operator
not applied to the value of the variable `valid`.
`while ( !valid )` means (literally) while the expression
`!valid` (which means "not valid") is true.

For the rest, the code you're copying is pretty bad.  I wouldn't
use it as an example if I were you.

As for your own code:

- `_tmain` is very particular to Microsoft.  You don't want to
  use it.  If your writing a console application, just use `main`.
  (Same thing holds for `_TCHAR`, rather than `char`.)
- Neither `_tmain` nor `main` can return a `float`.  The return
  type of `main` should always be `int`.  I'm less familiar with
  `_tmain`, but it's either `int` or `void`.  (Probably `int`, if
  you're in a console mode program.)
- `!true` is `false`.  Always.  (Programming is different than
  the real world.  There are no maybes.)  Why be more
  complicated than necessary?
- There's no need for the flag variable at all.  You
  can just write:

  cin >> operatorSelection;
  while ( !cin || operatorSelection > 4 || operatorSelection < 1 ) {
      //  ...
  }
- In case of error, you currently only ignore a single
  character.  You probably want to ignore up to and including the
  end of line.
  (`std::cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max() );`.
- And the condition in your if will always be true.  (See my
  version above.)  Where do you expect to find a number which is
  neither less than for nor greater than one?

Comment: Thank you for all of this; I've renamed `_tmain -> main` and `_TCHAR -> char`. I also simply forgot to put `int` back after a find-replace for `float`. Now I'm trying to wrap my mind around `( !cin || operatorSelection > 4 || operatorSelection < 1 )`, because (see my updated post) I'm being confused by `!cin` the same way I was by `!valid`.

Comment: @DarkIron112 It's quite understandable to be confused by `!cin`, because, of course, `cin` isn't a boolean. But it is designed so that it can be used "as if" it were a boolean.  And using it as such is ubiquitous in C++ code, so you'll have to get used to it.  (FWIW: using a stream as a boolean is the same a `!cin.fail()`.

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand that now; `!cin.fail()` IS a boolean that is flagged from using `cin`, right? Also, and I feel stupid for having to ask this; What is the difference between `std::cin` and `cin`? Is `std::` necessary if I have `using namespace std;` at the beginning?

Comment: @DarkIron112 The full name is `std::cin`, and this is what I use, almost systematically.  If you have `using namespace std;` at the top of your source, the `std::` isn't necessary; in large applications, I don't like doing this, since `using namespace std;` pulls in so many symbols.

Comment: I've implemented your suggestions into a test code which loops infinitely; Find a new question for you here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18131903/why-is-this-code-snippet-infinitely-looping

Answer (score 2):

You want to run the loop "**while** there is **not** a **valid** input". Remove the non-bold words, and translate to C++.

Of course, the second case is not working, because nothing changes `validInput` inside the loop, so it stays "invalid", and the loop continues forever (And if you want to set something to `false` then  `bool validInput = !true;` is more convoluted than `bool validInput = false;` - the compiler will do the same thing, but someone reading the code will have to think to see what it does - it is a good thing to think when reading code, but it's not a good thing to write code that is more complicated than necessary...).

Answer (score 2):

The `!` operator is a logical `not` and this is how you should read it: `while not valid`. You could have also written that as:

```
while(valid == false)
```

or

```
while(valid != true)
```

Note that here, again, `!=` is equivalent to `not equal`.

Comment: There is never any case when comparing a `bool` to `true` or `false` is an acceptable coding practice.  In his case, `valid` is a `bool`.  The comparison has a result of type `bool`.  If you need a comparison to evaluate a type `bool`, then you need a comparison after that as well: `(valid == false) == true`.  Except that that also results in a `bool`, so you need another comparison.  Ad infititum.

Comment: @JamesKanze Bad habit yes, however for explaining to a new programmer it works as a clear explanation of an equivalent to `!valid`. At compile time it should all be optimised down to the same condition anyway.

Comment: @JamesKanze You are right - if SO would natively support it, I had provided a truth table, but doing that with ASCII art is too exhausting ;)

Answer (score 2):

In your code, inside the loop, just add:

```
else
  validInput = true;
```

after the `if` closing bracket.
You want to get out of it once the user has typed a correct value.

Comment: Not an answer to his question, but it would be much more idiomatic to test `cin` and the variables directly in the `while` condition, and omit the variable completely.

Answer (score 2):

A while loop has a condition and a body, the body is executed as long as the condition evaluates to true.

From the C++ standard:

> 6.5.1 The while statement
>
> In the while statement the substatement is executed repeatedly until the value of the condition (6.4) becomes
>   false. The test takes place before each execution of the substatement.

A while loop can have one of the following forms

`while ( condition ) statement`

```
while ( condition )
{
  statement(s)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

nijansen forgot to add the most elegant one

```
while(!valid)
```

which is the same as the 2 others

Comment: Not quite the same.  It's simple, logical and readable.  The other 2 aren't.

Comment: That's the one I want to use because it's elegant; But WHY it works boggles me, I can't translate it from C++ -> Mental Concept.

Comment: ! - is a logic operator "not" 

"if" enter the brackets in case of any number that is not "0" adding "!" in the beginning of the value, turn the sentence upside down, means "only 0"