# Why is this code snippet infinitely looping?

Tags: c++, while-loop, infinite-loop, cin

I'm fairly new to programming, and  I'm trying to filter inputs from `cin` (for no particular reason; It is the only input method I know of right now) such that one can only enter 1-10 and get the "positive" response. Here is my code:

```
#pragma region Check cin is a valid input (an integer between 1 and 10, not a string or number out of range)
int input;
bool valid2=false;
    while (!valid2)
    {
        cout << "Enter an integer (1-10): ";
        cin >> input;
        if (!cin || input > 10 || input < 1)
        {
            cout << "Error: Invalid. Try again." << endl << endl;
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max());
            cin.clear();
        }
        else
        {
            valid2 = true;
        }
    }
#pragma endregion
```

Ignore the "pragma", I have one test script with blocks for each little experiment to save me time and this is just how I collapse them when they're no longer valid.

My problem (among others) is that when I enter a non-integer such as `f`, it loops infinitely with `"Error: Invalid. Try Again"`, and I can't figure out why. I thought maybe since `input` became defined, it was running past `cin` when it comes back around. But I checked an isolated example, and `cin` let me specifically redefine `input` before continuing.

Sidebar: Speaking of `pragma`, does anyone have a better method for this in c++? Aside from making individual methods, because most of my tests can just run inside `main`.

**EDIT:**
I've switched `cin.ignore(...)` and `cin.clear()` and now the program can properly filter the inputs; however now, it doesn't loop back at all. After giving me `"Error: Invalid. Try again."`, it hangs where it *should* ask me again to enter the integer.

Comment: You need `cin.clear()` before `cin.ignore()`, as `cin.ignore()` first does a check to see if the input is `good` before going on - and it isn't when there is an error...

Comment: If I understand my own code correctly, the `while` uses an `if` to check `cin`; if `cin` is acceptable, `valid2` is flipped to `true`, which them allows the `while` to end. Right?

Comment: Ignore my above; I responded to a now deleted comment.

Comment: @MatsPetersson But if I use `cin.clear()`, what does `cin.ignore()` have left to ignore? Maybe I don't understand what it does very well.

Comment: `cin.clear()` clears all error states.  It has no effect on the input data.  If your stream is in an error state(`bad` or `fail`), you need to clear it before doing pretty much anything else, as most operations will simply fail if there is an error flag set.

Comment: After swapping `cin.clear()` and `cin.ignore()` lines, it seems to filter properly (anything other than 1-10 gives the error), however it doesn't loop back to receive a new line; It appears to hang inside the `if`...

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't loop back - is it hung in the cout, the cin or the ignore?

Comment: @Useless I'm not sure; Not the `cout`, It prints `Error: Invalid. Try Again.` followed by two `endl`'s like it should, but immediately after that. Maybe the ignore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original code has TWO problems (at least as far as I've spotted - not guaranteeing there aren't any more):

1. The order of `cin.clear()` and `cin.ignore()` - `cin.clear()` should be before `cin.ignore()`, or `cin.ignore()` will do nothing.
2. The `cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max());` is reading until the delimiter, which defaults to `EOF` - in other words, no matter what input is in the buffer, or entered after, it keeps on accepting it.

To fix both problems use this:

```
  cin.clear();
  cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

that will read until the end of the current line, which is probably more along the lines of what you want.

Oh, and change:

```
    cin >> input;
    if (!cin || input > 10 || input < 1)
```

to:

```
    if (!(cin >> input) || input > 10 || input < 1)
```

Comment: You should take back that last edit.  That would be `if ( (!cin) >> input ... ` which is not going to work.  I thought about `while ( !(cin >> input) ||...` in my previous answer (which is probably the most idiomatic), but decided that if he's having problems understanding a simple `bool` variable, `!(cin >> input)` would be a bit too much for him to bite off at one go.

Comment: I'll do whatever works, fellows; I understand `!cin` well enough, that it's a special-case that can work in a boolean way. But is there a functional difference between `!(cin >> input)` and `!cin`, or is it just how it's spelled out?

Comment: The difference is that you are using the typical style of C++ with the latter. Both will work in this case.

Comment: @MatsPetersson I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, because `!cin` works perfectly, but `!(cin >> input)` does not; If I type a letter like `f`, it gives me the error like it should. But if I enter a number (in or out of range) it skips to the next line and, without prompting, waits for another number. Is putting `!(cin >> input)' inside `if` causing it to try and evaluate the `cin >> input` inside the `if` conditions order to *obtain* a condition?