# How does this bool variable work exactly?

Tags: c++, boolean

I am new to programming, so please forgive me if my question is too basic.

For the following code, I don't know how exactly the bool variable "more" works. It says that while loop will do the content of the loop whenever the "more" is true, but

1. how does the computer know that the more is true? Is it smart enough to know that "more" literally means when the user inputs additional value through keyboard? Also, does it know that a negative input is not considered "more" but only positive input is considered "more"?
2. Inside the while loop, it says that the more is false when the input value is 0. However, it does not logically make sense that more is false when it already goes through the while loop, which only runs when the more is true!
3. I learned that we will get an infinite loop when "while is always true". It seems like the while loop will always be true since more = true.

Please help me out with this question!!

```
vector<double> salaries;
cout << "Please enter salaries, 0 to quit:" << endl;
bool more = true;
while (more)
{
  double s;
  cin >> s;    
  if (s == 0)
    more = false;
  else
    salaries.push_back(s);
}
```

Comment: Are you using a debugger? Then you can examine your variable as it changes.  You set more=false; which will exit the loop...(when s == 0)

Comment: you should compare a `double` with another `double`. i.e.) `if (s == 0 /*int*/)` should be `if (s == 0.0 /*double*/)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you explain HOW bool can control loops?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18129174/can-you-explain-how-bool-can-control-loops)

Comment: `more` is a memory location in the computer's RAM chips. The `while()` constructs checks the contents of the memory location called `more` and if it contains the binary equivalent of `true` it executes the body of the loop.

Comment: *"Inside the while loop, it says that the more is false when the input value is 0."* - It is not reporting on the value of `more`. It is instructing `more` to *become* false if the input has a certain value. You can read is as **Let *more* become *false***

Comment: Is this an elaborate troll?

Answer (score 5):

Ok, so point by point:

1) The compiler knows that `more` is true because on line 3 it says:

```
bool more = true;
```

This creates the bool `more` and gives it the value `true`.

2) `more` is then *set* to `false` if `s` is equal to `zero`. Although `more` is true at the beginning of the loop there is nothing to say it can't be changed within the loop (this is called mutability).

3) Because `more` gets set to false within the loop, the loop will stop executing. This will only happen if someone enters `0` for the input. If this doesn't happen you are correct, the loop will get run forever.

This is a fairly common while loop construct which allows an arbitrary number of values to be added to the vector `salaries`. In your question you hint that positive numbers should not be allowed, it is worth noting that there is nothing in the code enforcing this. Perhaps it would be better to change the line:

```
if (s == 0)
```

to:

```
if (s <= 0.0)
```

This way the loop will stop executing if a `0` value is entered *or* if a negative value is entered.

Answer (score 5):

(1): The computer (or the compiler) is not smart enough to connect `more` to a literal meaning.

(2): `more` can be changed inside the loop, which is what happens when you enter `0`. After changing `more` to `false`, the condition in `while (more)` is re-evaluated. As `more` is now false, the loop is exited.

(3): No, `more` is not always true, see (2).

Comment: Yes, I guess the OP needs to understand that the condition in `while (more)` is re-evaluated in every iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 3):

In your code snippet variable `more` is explicitly set two times: before the loop and inside the loop if s is equal to zero

```
bool more = true;
while (more)
{
  //...
  if (s == 0)
    more = false;
  //..
}
```

Thus when more will be set to false within the body of the loop

```
  if (s == 0)
    more = false;
```

the loop stops its iterations because the condition in while will not true

```
while (more)
```

Take into account that the condition above is equivalent to

```
while (more == true)
```

Though there is no great sense to write such a way because variable more is already a boolean expression.

Also take into account that according to the C++ Standard

4.12 Boolean conversions

> 1 A prvalue of arithmetic, unscoped enumeration, pointer, or pointer
>   to member type can be converted to a prvalue of type bool. A zero
>   value, null pointer value, or null member pointer value is converted
>   to false; any other value is converted to true. For
>   direct-initialization (8.5), a prvalue of type std::nullptr_t can be
>   converted to a prvalue of type bool; the resulting value is false.

You could rewrite your code snippet in other way without using variable more. For example

```
vector<double> salaries;

cout << "Please enter salaries, 0 to quit:" << endl;

double s;
while ( cin >> s && s != 0 )
{
    salaries.push_back(s);
}
```

Or the condition in while could be written even like

```
while ( cin >> s && s )
```

So according to the quote of the C++ Standard if s is not equal to 0 then it is converted to bool true. As for expression cin >> s then class std::istream has explicit conversion operator that converts std::cin to boolean value if the stream is not in erroneous state.

Answer (score 2):

The variable `more` is explicitly set to `true` before the loop is entered. In the loop's body, if `more` is set `false`, nothing else is executed in the loop's body afterwards. The flow of execution goes again to the beginning of the loop, where the loop's condition is evaluated. As `more` is `false`, the loop's body is not executed again.

Answer (score 1):

1. No, the computer(compiler, more appropriate) does not know the intent behind your coding, specifics behind your variables and functions, It only working on set of instructions, which need to be syntactically correct. 
   in `while(more)` it's job is to run the loop for as long as more `boolean` is `true` and skip to next instruction when `false`.
2. `while(condition)`,here condition is checked once for every iteration, and during the iteration, the compiler does not bother to check and skip the rest of the code upon more being `false`. the condition is checked only before beginning an iteration.
3. Absolutely, just assume `while(true){set of instructions;}` the condition is always true and therefore the block of code is always executed and we call this an `Infinite Loop`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems that you don't really understand the way your compiler works.

First of all, your computer is not smart or dumb, it's merely a machine and interprets whatever you give them to. So, it all comes to the way you have programmed your program. Having said that we move on:

The

```
while(condition) {
commands;
}
```

loop works basically as follows:

- It checks the `condition` whatever that might be at the time it your
  program flow enters the loop.
- It continues to execute whatever `commands` are if and only if the previous checked condition was `true`.
- If it wasn't true then your programs continues to execute whatever command follow your `while` loop.
- When the execution of `commands` have finished it goes again to check the `condition` in `while`.
- Again, if it's true it carries on with `commands`.
- If not, then again it continues to the following your `while` commands.

So, to sum up, your compiler, computer or your digital friend does not check for logical flows in how you name your variables, if `false` does not make sense, etc. It merely checks if `condition` is `true`. That's it.

Finally an infinite loop will occur if the initial `condition` was `true` when entering the loop and when exiting the loop always continues to be true (not does not change inside the loop because it could change and also get a `true` values when exiting the loop).

Answer (score 0):

You have some misunderstandings with how things work in C++. You can think of your program as an abstract machine. Each variable is a storage location that maintains some state. The `more` variable is an example of this state. You can think of the variable as a location in memory that maintains the value that you give it. The total program state is allowed to change throughout the duration of the runtime of the program.

Each assignment (the `=` operator) sets the state of the variable to the value on the right hand side of the assignment.

So when you say:

```
bool more = true;
```

The storage location named `more` is set to the value `true`. The storage location will remain `true` until you assign a new value to it.

Note that in C++ statements are evaluated sequentially. Since the values of the variables may change over time, the order of the statements matters.

Later on when you say:

```
while (more)
{
    // ...
}
```

The first time that `more` is evaluated, it is `true`, but again, since `more` is a **variable**, that value may change over time.

Once you are inside the `while` loop, the `more` variable is **conditionally** assigned false when the variable `s` is equal to `0`. Notice that the `==` is truly an equality check unlike the `=` operator.

```
    if (s == 0)
        more = false;
```

Note that you should be aware that `s` is of type `double` and the literal `0` is of type `int`. Fortunately for you, this will work since C++ will automatically promote the `int` to a `double` type to do the equality comparison. However, it probably makes since to use a literal `0.0` to be clear that you expect for `s` to be a `double`.

Since the value of `s` is dependent on the value that is read from `cin`, the equality condition will sometimes be `true` and sometimes `false` depending on what is entered by the user. But if `more` is assigned `false`, it when then cause the `while` loop to terminate on its next iteration. In other words, when you reach the close brace `}` the program will repeat back to the beginning of the `while` and try to re-evaluate `more`, at that point, when `more` is `false` the `while` loop will end.

Answer (score 0):

```
vector<double> salaries;
cout << "Please enter salaries, 0 to quit:" << endl;
bool more = true;
while (more)
{
  double s;
  cin >> s;    
  if (s == 0)
    more = false;
  else
    salaries.push_back(s);
}
```

A `while` loop will iterate over and over until the condition between the `()`is not met. When you start the cycle you start with `bool more = true;` That way you're telling the `while(more)` loop to keep iterating while `more` is true. Inside the code you ask for input with `cin >> s;` and if the input is 0 the variable `more` will change to `false`, it will iterate again and since `while(more)` is awaiting for the `more`variable to be `true` the condition won't be `true` and the cycle will end. If you input other value than `0` the cycle will store that value into the `vector<double> salaries` vector.

One way for getting the values that were stored in the vector is:

`for(int i = 0; i<salaries.size(); i++){
  cout<< salaries[i] << endl;
}`

In which case you're telling the compiler to iterate with a variable called `i` starting from the value `0` until the value of `i` is `<` than the value of `salaries.size()`, for each iteration, `i` will increase and when the condition is no longer met, the cycle will end.

As a recomendation, use the `std` namespace for your types, it will be of help in future code to avoid bringing everything from the `std` namespace into your code.

```
std::vector<double> salaries;
std::cout << "Please enter salaries, 0 to quit:" << std::endl;
bool more = true;
while (more)
{
  double s;
  std::cin >> s;    
  if (s == 0)
    more = false;
  else
    salaries.push_back(s);
}
```

and

`for(int i = 0; i<salaries.size(); i++){
  std::cout<< salaries[i] << std::endl;
}`